# How Do I get the Process ID within a VB Form of a Process I Launched with that VB Form?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I'm using a form I made in VB2005 to open a program upon button press and then in a text field display the Process ID (again upon button press). When I run it the form will open the program (Notepad.exe) but when I click the button to view the Process ID Visual Studio 2005 says:

InvalidCastException was unhandled and highlights the line "TextBox1.Text = ProcID"

```
Imports System
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class Form1

    Dim myProcess As New Process
    Dim ProcID

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Launch.Click
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe"
        myProcess.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetID_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GetID.Click
        ProcID = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
        TextBox1.Text = ProcID
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

End Class
```

When I try to change the ProcID declaration into a string by:

```
    Dim ProcID As String
```

VS2005 gives the error:

> Value of type 'System.Diagnostics.Process' cannot be converted to 'String'.

I've tried declaring the Dim ProcID As Integer and got:

> Value of type 'System.Diagnostics.Process' cannot be converted to 'Integer'.

I've also tried the following change with no luck:

```
Private Sub GetID_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles GetID.Click
    ProcID = Process.GetCurrentProcess(myProcess)
    TextBox1.Text = CInt(ProcID)
End Sub
```

That error says:

> Class 'System.Diagnostics.Process' cannot be indexed because it has no default property.

Please help! This is driving me crazy!

Thanks

Comment: What is today? VS-2005 awareness day or what? :) (involved in another questions with VS 2005 a while ago). Sorry cannot help (don't have VS 2005 and cannot be sure if this is not the source of the problem); just want to suggest you to move to a newer VS and a small correction: it is VS 2005. VB follows a different numeration; it corresponds to VB 8.0 according to Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following change will get you the process ID and put it into the textbox.

```
 ProcID = Process.GetCurrentProcess.Id
 TextBox1.Text = ProcID.ToString
```

Comment if you have issues.